# Restoring few tables in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

**Introduction:**

Hi, we use SQL Server 2016 Servers for App DBs (437 Applications) in our corporation. We have other environments (Such as HCM etc.,) from which data has to be available for these applications.

To meet this requirement, we have a shared DB with name CentralRepository to which data flows from other environments and make it available for these DBs.

**Problem Description:**

Now we are trying to migrate few of the critical applications(26) to Azure servers. Hence, we have to move the CentralRepository as well to make sure the necessary data is available for the applications. But moving the whole DB is waste of resources as we don't require the tables necessary for rest 410 DBs. Hence, we are planning to move the data necessary for these 26 applications i.e., around 110+ tables out of hundreds of tables.

I would like to know if there is any way we can do that other than using Import/Export Wizard (tough to move 110 tables data to all the Azure environments) or complete DB restoration (as it is relatively very huge DB).

It would be very helpful, if you can suggest work around this problem. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You could create a new DB, copy these tables to it, back up the DB, and then restore it where ever you want. I'm sure there's 1000 other gotchas in your environment, though. I'd expect these tables to at least be in their own schema, if not their own DB entirely.

Comment: You can't do a partial backup or restore, if that's what your asking. When you perform a backup/restore your backup/restore the whole database; not parts of it.. You'll either need to restore the whole database, and then `DROP` the objects you don't require, script out everything you need, or use an ETL process (like the Import/Export wizard, although, personally i'd suggest doing it properly in SSIS; the wizard can be quirky).

Comment: @scsimon Thanks a lot for the suggestions :)
But in that case, we would lose all the access and permissions that were previously granted. We will have to work on the DB from scratch(Including view creation and their individual permissions which is relatively tough).

Comment: you can also script out logons... just FYSA.